# How to make a button to use json data on android

Tags: java, android, json, button

I am sorry if this is a silly question, I am new to json data and new to android and programming in general.

What I have in mind is, for example to utilize json data like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "Test",
        type: "Liquid",
        amount: 13,
        stat: 1
    }
]
```

Just a random example. What I wish to achieve with it is that in app, there is a button for "stat" that switches it from 1 to 0 or vice versa, and to show a panel where it reads the "amount". Is that possible to achieve?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here jsonString is your json:

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
int stat=array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("stat");
int amount=array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("amount");
}
```

Now use according to your convenience.